# Right align menu items without reversing them using CSS

Tags: html, css

How do I get all my menu items (apart from home) to sit on the right hand side without their order being reversed (i.e keep Features as the first item).

Please see my code below:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body { font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:10pt; color:#828282; }
.header {padding: 10px;}
.header ul {list-style: none;}
.header ul li {display: inline}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        <li><a href="#">Features</a>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a>
        <li><a href="#">Sign up</a>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="shout">
<a href="#">Start</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to move entire menu on right side (like this: http://prntscr.com/973qpw) ?

Comment: @DejanMunjiza The whole menu apart from "Home" which I want kept on the left

Comment: Ok, I posted it as answer. Anyway, here is a fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/0s1uxhu5/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to move entire menu on right side, you can use float: right for your ul element. In your case it would be:

```
.header ul {float: right;}
```

Working fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/vpygzyyx/1/

EDIT: Here is an update with HOME on left side and rest of the menu on right side of header:

```
.header ul {list-style: none; text-align:right;}
.header ul li {display: inline}
.header ul li:first-child{float:left}
```

**Fiddle demo link:** https://jsfiddle.net/vpygzyyx/2/

Answer (score 3):

Use `direction: rtl;` and `float: left;` on `li:first-child`. See the snippet

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  color: #828282;
}
.header {
  padding: 10px;
}
.header ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.header ul li {
  display: inline
}
ul {
  direction: rtl;
}
li:first-child {
  float: left
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Features</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sign up</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="shout">
  <a href="#">Start</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to make two menu for that, and you can achieve your output, try following code :-

```
<div class="header">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="right-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Css will be :-

```
.header .right-menu{
   float: right;
}
```

It may help you.

Comment: This will float the right menu under the left, the left menu needs to float:left too.

Comment: Sorry its my mistake. :)

Answer (score 1):

As in this [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/0s1uxhu5/2/), give the `.header` right `text-align` and then `float:left` the first child of the list - *you forgot to close the `li` tags*

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  color: #828282;
}
.header {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right;
}
.header ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.header ul li {
  display: inline
}
.header ul li:first-child {
  float: left
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="shout">
<a href="#">Start</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Split your `ul` into a `.left-menu` for Home and a `.right-menu` for the other items then add `float:left` to the `left-menu` and `float:right` to `right-menu`, finally add the [clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) to the header to force your other elements down below the menu:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body { font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; ; color:#828282; }
.header {padding: 10px;}
.: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
.header ul {list-style: none;}
.header ul.left-menu {float: left;}
.header ul.right-menu {float: right;}
.header ul li {display: inline}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <ul class="left-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="right-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="shout">
<a href="#">Start</a>
</div>
```